# what is the meaning in casting base class constructor to derived class constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, base-class, derived

```
class Triangle: public Shape{
      public:
             Triangle(int a=0, int b=0):Shape(a,b){}
             int area()
             {
                 cout << "in triangle class";
                 return width*height/2;
             }
};
```

in the above code, wt is the meaning of the line

```
Triangle(int a=0, int b=0):Shape(a,b){}
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate of something, but you can't search for ":" in the finder :)

Comment: +1 (-1 plus +1 -> 0) For asking a question that others may thinks is dumb or is duplicated, but, deserves to be answered

Answer (score 1):

If `Derived` class inherits `Base` class, then when constructing a `Derived` object, the constructor of `Derived` class must call the constructor of `Base` class. The `Destructor`s of these classes will be called in reversed order. In `Triangle(int a=0, int b=0):Shape(a,b){}`, the `Triangle` constructor is calling `Shape` constructor passing the required arguments. There is no casting involved. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539282/order-of-calling-constructors-destructors-in-inheritance) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078417/inheritance-hierachy-constructor-destructor-execution-sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is being cast here. The `Triangle` constructor is invoking the `Shape` base class' constructor with the parameter list, `(a,b)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no cast here. This is a constructor initialization list.

When you construct a `Triangle`, since `Shape` is a base class, it must construct a `Shape` first. The list `Shape(a,b)` says that `a,b` are the arguments given to the constructor for this `Shape`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
class Triangle: public Shape{
      public:
             Triangle(int a=0, int b=0):Shape(a,b)
             {
               // may do something
             }

             int area()
             {
                 cout << "in triangle class";
                 return width*height/2;
             }
};
```

How does internally work:

```
class Triangle: public Shape{
          public:
                     Triangle(int a=0, int b=0):
                 {
                   // always before the others instructions
                   base(a,b);

                   // may do something
                 }

                 int area()
                 {
                     cout << "in triangle class";
                     return width*height/2;
                 }
    };
```

There are several ways to work with constructors:

(1) Declare a new class with a new constructor

```
class NewConstructorClass: public SomeBaseClass // dont care about parent class constructor
{
   NewConstructorClass {
     // do something new instruction 1
     // do something new instruction 2
     // do something new instruction 3
   }

  public:
    void DoAnything()
    {
      // ...
    }
};
```

(2) Declare a new class with a new and empty, constructor. Some developers do this, in order, to add code to the constructor, later, or, explicitly, add an empty constructor, as a "best practice", to indicate that there should be a constructor.

```
class NewConstructorClass: public SomeBaseClass // dont care about parent class constructor
{
   NewConstructorClass {
     // does nothing, on purpouse
   }

  public:
    void DoAnything()
    {
      // ...
    }
};
```

(3) Declare a new class without a new constructor. The compilers adds an automatic constructor that does nothing.

```
class NewConstructorClass: public SomeBaseClass // dont care about parent class constructor
{
   NewConstructorClass {
     // do something new
   }

  public:
    void DoAnything()
    {
      // ...
    }
};
```

(4) Declare a new class with a new constructor, that calls the base constructor. Like your scenario:

```
class NewConstructorClass: public SomeBaseClass // dont care about parent class constructor
{
   NewConstructorClass: base() {
     // do something new
   }

  public:
    void DoAnything()
    {
      // ...
    }
};
```

Each case, depends, on what you want to achieve. Some of this cases, may be consider "Bad practices", others "good practices", depending on coding styles.

Cheers.